# Canonical 1-form and Lie bracket of standard horizontal vector fields.

Tags: differential-geometry

I am using Kobayashi & Nomizu's book to study some elementary differential geometry and got stuck on Proposition III.5.4 (p.136). The proposition is

Let $B$ and $B'$ be arbitrary standard horizontal vector fields on $L(M)$ (the frame bundle).  Then we have

(a) If $T=0$, then $[B,B']$ is vertical.

(b) If $R=0$, then $[B,B']$ is horizontal.

($T$ is the torsion tensor, $R$ is the curvature tensor).  The statement (b) is straightforward.  But in the proof of statement (a), they use the equation $\theta([B,B'])=-2d\theta(B,B')=-2\Theta(B,B')=0$ by the structure equation, where $\theta$ is the canonical 1-form and $\Theta$ is the torsion 2-form.  I am not sure if this equation is correct in general.  Can someone please offer some hints?  Thanks very much.

Comment: Look at the formula for $d\omega(X,Y)$ and the structure equation for $d\theta$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the comments.  The structure equation of $d\theta$ is $d\theta=-\omega\wedge\theta+\Theta$, which immediately gives the second equality.  My main question is of the first equality.  Given the general formula for 1-form is $d\theta(X,Y)=\frac{1}{2}(X\theta(Y)-Y\theta(X)-\theta([X,Y]))$, I don't know how to eliminate the first two terms in the bracket if B,B' are both horizontal.  I'm not sure the formula for $d\omega(X,Y)$ is relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we want to use the structure equation. You have $d\theta(B,B') = \theta(B)\omega(B') - \theta(B')\omega(B) + \Theta(B,B') = \Theta(B,B')$ because $\omega(B)=\omega(B')=0$. On the other hand, using the formula for $d\theta$, recall that $B(\theta(B')) = B'(\theta(B)) = 0$ when $B$ and $B'$ are *standard* horizontal vector fields (because $\theta(B)$ and $\theta(B')$ are fixed elements of $\Bbb R^n$). [The equation does not hold for arbitrary horizontal vector fields.]

Comment: Like I said, the structure equation only answer the second inequality.  I want to ask the first one, the commutator one.  Why is $\theta([B,B’])=-2d\theta(B,B’)$.  Is that a special property of horizontal vector fields?

Comment: Did you even read what I wrote?!

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I didn't read the second part (after the "on the other hand").  I read your comment too quickly.  Thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome. When you're satisfied with the answer, please accept it so that the question will no longer be "unanswered."